# What are eliminated assumptions, informally?

Tags: logic

In the [text](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/setsproofs17alt-RL.pdf) (WARNING: this is a large pdf) I'm using proof trees are defined very formally, and I'm trying to recover the point of defining eliminated assumptions (on page 98). Can someone explain the reason behind placing a dagger in front of assumptions or maybe suggest some terms I can google on? Googling 'eliminated assumption' doesn't give any results.

With explaining the point I mean something like this:

If we assume that propositions $P$ and $Q$ are true, then also the proposition "$P$ and $Q$" is true, so in a proof tree we want to be able to write $\phi \wedge \psi$ as root with $\phi$ and $\psi$ as leafs.

Comment: "Non-bureaucratically"?

Comment: @anomaly not formal, but on a basic level, is that not how you say it in English?

Comment: No, that's cool; just wanted to know if you were looking for something that's informal but basically correct and designed for mathematicians, or something that's casual enough for the outside world. (There are a lot of questions here along the lines of "What's the intuition behind [thing]", and the answer depends on the audience.)

Comment: @anomaly Ah ok. I was looking for something that's informal but basically correct and designed for mathematicians

Comment: I edited the title hopefully to more accurately reflect your intentions.

Comment: I've just accidentally downloaded the PDF to my phone by clicking the link  (I was expecting an image of a page). Maybe add a warning that it's a PDF?

Comment: I  mean I don't mind getting a free 178-page book on proof theory, but it's not quite what I expected to happen!

Comment: Trying Googling "discharging assumptions." I don't know anything about "proof trees," but I'm guessing it means the same thing.

Comment: @timtfj Sweet. Adding that to my library.

Comment: See the post [What does it mean to "discharge assumptions or premises"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3920/what-does-it-mean-to-discharge-assumptions-or-premises)